# C# UWP "Subscribe to value changes"

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

```
private async void Characteristic_ValueChanged(GattCharacteristic sender, GattValueChangedEventArgs args)
        {

            // BT_Code: An Indicate or Notify reported that the value has changed.
            // Display the new value with a timestamp.
            var newValue = FormatValueByPresentation(args.CharacteristicValue, presentationFormat);
            var message = $"Value at {DateTime.Now:hh:mm:ss}: {newValue}";
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                () => CharacteristicLatestValue.Text = message);
        }
```

This is a sample from github. Universal BluetoothLE samples. I'm facing a problem now where if I click the "read" button, it displays my rfduino reading. But because I want it to update automatically whenever the value change, I need to subscribe to value change.

However, when I click "Subscribe to value change", all I receive is just "Unknown format". Anyone expert can help me to solve this step by step ? IF possible, we can use Teamviewer.

```
private async void CharacteristicReadButton_Click()
        {
             // BT_Code: Read the actual value from the device by using Uncached.
            GattReadResult result = await selectedCharacteristic.ReadValueAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
            if (result.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
            {
                string formattedResult = FormatValueByPresentation(result.Value, presentationFormat);

                rootPage.NotifyUser($"Read result: {formattedResult}", NotifyType.StatusMessage);  
            }
            else
            {
                rootPage.NotifyUser($"Read failed: {result.Status}", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
            }     
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

First you can subscribe to characteristic value changes notification if characteristic has Indicatable or Notifiable properties. it is not always the same that your read from. It can be other characteristic.

Once you found your characteristic you have to write ClientConfigurationDescriptor of that characteristic with Indicatable or Notifiable properties set to True. It notifies GATT server that client is interested in change event for this characteristic.

And only that you can subscribe and be notified. Also once notification arrived you do not need to read from characteristic cause notification event includes new characteristic value.

Answer (score -1):

Your coding skills are not enough to understand what is going on.
Break down your wishes to exchange values  between Rfuino and your uwp app.
To send values you have to make some protocol to know when a valid message has arrived.
If Rfuino allows you to send a byte-array do something like sending a start-byte then 
your values as bytes and a end byte. like STX,value X, value Y , value Z ,ETX .(2,255,255,255,3).
if on the receiving end you read a message like 2, 148,250,180,3 then you know a valid message has arrived.
I don't know much about Rfuino, but most ble-devices can send a message like that.
Also the UWP example is to complicated for you to understand.
In your UWP app you can check if your message has a length of 5 bytes and starts with 2 and ends with 3.
Have a look at my simple Ble example on GitHub: https://github.com/GrooverFromHolland/SimpleBleExample_by_Devicename
If you have problems with that example  or want to  extend it start an issue on GitHub.
Stop asking questions over this  subject on Stackoverflow, you will get some answers, but we are not here to teach you how to code.

Comment: If you have a problem with the example post an issue on Github.